# ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs excel 2013 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2013, save-as

I am getting a

> Run-time error '1004' Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed.

The code works in excel 2010. I only get this error message in excel 2013.
The error message appears after trying to run the follow line.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & NewSaveExt, 52
```

Background:
The spreadsheet is an .xls
When using the Saveas I am changing it to .xlsm
I have tried it with a .xls extension and fileformat 56 and it still falls over.
I am using code from the resources listed in the code.
I am saving the file to the same folder the workbook is in.
The orignal file name is: Financial Report as at month N.xls
The new filename is : Financial Report 1516 as at month 8.xlsm

```
    Sub SaveNewVersion_Excel()
    'PURPOSE: Save file, if already exists add a new version indicator to                 filename
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim SaveName As String
    Dim SaveExt As String
    Dim NewSaveExt As String
    Dim VersionExt As String
    Dim Saved As Boolean
    Dim x As Long

    TestStr = ""
    Saved = False
    x = 0
    NewSaveExt = ".xlsm"
    'Version Indicator (change to liking)
      VersionExt = "_v"

    'Pull info about file
      On Error GoTo NotSavedYet
        myPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        myFileName = "Financial Report " & FileFinancialYear & " as at month         " & MonthNumber
        FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
        SaveExt = "." & Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "."))
      On Error GoTo 0



    'Determine Base File Name
      If InStr(1, myFileName, VersionExt) > 1 Then
        myArray = Split(myFileName, VersionExt)
        SaveName = myArray(0)
      Else
        SaveName = myFileName
      End If


    'Test to see if file name already exists
      If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt) = False Then

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & NewSaveExt, 52
        Exit Sub
      End If

    'Need a new version made
      Do While Saved = False
        If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt) =         False Then
          ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & NewSaveExt, 52
          Saved = True
        Else
          x = x + 1
        End If
      Loop

    'New version saved
      MsgBox "New file version saved (version " & x & ")"

    Exit Sub

    'Error Handler
    NotSavedYet:
      MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
        "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"

    End Sub


    Function FileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean
    'PURPOSE: Test to see if a file exists or not
    'RESOURCE: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

    Dim TestStr As String

    'Test File Path (ie "S:\Reports\Financial Report as at...")
      On Error Resume Next
        TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
      On Error GoTo 0

    'Determine if File exists
      If TestStr = "" Then
        FileExist = False
      Else
        FileExist = True
      End If

    End Function
```

Comment: Whats MonthNumber? Not declared any where

Comment: Private MonthNumber As Integer. This is in another part of the code asking for the user input.MonthNumber = Application.InputBox(Prompt, Title, DefaultNumber, 250, 150, , , 1)

 From the immediate window ?Folderpath = "T:/Reports/" 
SaveName is "Financial Report 1516 as at month 8"

Comment: What is `NewSaveExt` - if it doesn't match the file type that you've specified then it will error

Comment: This is defined at the start of the code.    
        NewSaveExt = ".xlsm"
Reiterating what I have said above the current file type is xls 97/2003 I am saving it as .xlsm. It works in 2010 not in 2013.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some demonstration file with your code. Then we could reproduce and debug your issue.

Comment: I have put in the information required in a new sub. So you will be able to run it. However if I use this short cut it works in 2013 it does not throw up an error.

Sub Start()

    Msg = "Please enter the month you are reporting on, then click on 'OK' and continue from Guidance point 5."
    DefaultNumber = "Overtype with the month number here please."
    ErrMsg = ""
        MonthNumber = Application.InputBox(Prompt, Title, DefaultNumber, 250, 150, , , 1)

FinancialYear = "2015/2016"

FileFinancialYear = Mid(FinancialYear, 3, 2) & Mid(FinancialYear, 8, 2)

SaveNewVersion_Excel
End Sub

Comment: try to debug the values of the following vaaribles at runtime: FolderPath,SaveName,VersionExt,x,NewSaveExt. Check whether it forms a correct valid path to save the file.

Comment: @Karl have you tried the answer provided?

Answer (score 0):

**Error reproduction:**  I was able to reproduce the error when trying to save a workbook with a `FileName` that already exist.
This could happen because the code checks the existence of a file named with extension `SaveExt` *(using Function `FileExist`)* but then try to save it as a file named with extension `NewSaveExt`. If these extensions are not the same then it’s possible that the file named with extension `NewSaveExt` already exist raising the

> Run-time error ‘1004’: Method ‘SaveAs’ of object ‘_Workbook’ failed.

However this alert:

> A file ‘Financial Report as month .xlsm’ already exist in this
>   location. Do you want to replace it?.

Should have been displayed before the error `1004`

*Unfortunately I cannot test the code posted in Excel 2010, but I personally think this behavior is not exclusive of Excel 2013.*

**Solution:**  If the objective is to always save the file as `xlsm` *(value of `NewSaveExt`)* then the code should validate the existence of a filename with that extension.

**Additional comments about the code posted:**

1. It’s a best practice to declare all variables. These variables are not declared:
   `TestStr`, `FileFinancialYear`, `MonthNumber`, `myFileName`, `myArray`
2. These lines are redundant as no need to initialize variables that have not been used as yet, so they are already holding their initialized value.
   `TestStr = ""`; `Saved = False`; `x = 0`
3. Suggest to use constant instead of variables for these (see [Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html)) 
   `NewSaveExt = ".xlsm"`; `VersionExt = "_v"`
4. New workbooks are not detected as the error handler `NotSavedYet` which is supposed to be triggered when the `ActiveWorkbook` has not been saved before *(i.e. a new workbook)* never gets fired as none of the commands between the `On Error` statements generate an error when dealing with new workbooks *(see [On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx))*. If the intention is not to save `New Workbooks`, as implied by the error handler `NotSavedYet`, then validate the `Path` of the `ActiveWorkbook`, it will be empty if the workbook has not has been saved before.
5. The `FileFinancialYear` and `MonthNumber` variables never get populated.
6. Suggest to use specific workbook properties for `Path` and `Name` instead of `FullName` (see [Workbook Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835568.aspx))
7. About the piece referred as `Determine Base File Name`

   a. Programming: There is no need for `IF` statement, just use the `Split` function and take the item `0`. The `Split` function returns *”a single-element array containing the `entire`expression” when the `delimiter` is not present in the `expression`” (i.e. `VersionExt` and `myFileName` respectively)*.

   b. Practicality: This piece seems to be redundant, as it’s meant to extract from variable `myFileName` the filename excluding the version and extension, however there is no such information in the variable as it has been populate just few lines above as:

   `myFileName = "Financial Report " & FileFinancialYear & " as at month " & MonthNumber`

   Therefore `SaveName` is always equal to `myFileName`
8. The first version of the file is indexed as `0` instead of `1`.
9. *The new indexed version will not always be the last index number + 1*. If any of the previous versions is deleted or moved out to another folder as this version is missing the code will assign the missing version index to the latest file saved *(see Fig. 1, note that time of the version 3 is newer than versions 4 & 5)*. *Correction of this point requires a more complex approach as such it is not included in the revised code below.*

**Requirements:** Based on the above a revised code is written that complies with the following requirements:

- *The procedure resides in a standalone workbook.*
- Files are always saved as `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` *(Extension `xlsm`)*
- New workbooks will not be saved as new versions.
- Variables `FileFinancialYear` and `MonthNumber` are hardcoded as there is no indication of how they get populated *(change as required)*.
- The first time a file is saved and it does not exist in the source folder the file will be saved without version number.
- The index of the first version should be `1` *(change to 0 if required)*.

  ```
  Option Explicit


  Sub Wbk_SaveNewVersion_Xlsm()
  Const kExt As String = ".xlsm"
  Const kVrs As String = "_v"

  Dim WbkAct As Workbook
  Dim iYear As Integer, bMnth As Byte, sWbkStd As String
  Dim sWbkPthNme As String, bVrs As Byte

      Rem Set Standard Workbook Name
      iYear = 2015    'Update Financial Year as required
      bMnth = 9       'Update Month as required
      sWbkStd = "Financial Report " & iYear & " as at month " & Format(bMnth, "00")

      Rem Validate Active Workbook
      Set WbkAct = ActiveWorkbook
      If WbkAct.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then GoTo HdeThs
      If WbkAct.Path = Empty Then GoTo NewWbk

      Rem Get Workbook Properties
      sWbkPthNme = WbkAct.Path & "\" & sWbkStd

      Rem Validate Base File Existance
      If Not (Fil_FileExist(sWbkPthNme & kExt)) Then
          WbkAct.SaveAs sWbkPthNme & kExt, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
          MsgBox "A new workbook has been created: " & _
              vbLf & vbLf & Chr(34) & sWbkStd & kExt & Chr(34), _
              vbApplicationModal + vbInformation, "Workbook - Save a New Version - Xlsm"
          Exit Sub
      End If

      Rem Save a New Version
      bVrs = 1
      sWbkPthNme = sWbkPthNme & kVrs
      Do
          If Fil_FileExist(sWbkPthNme & bVrs & kExt) Then
              bVrs = 1 + bVrs
          Else
              WbkAct.SaveAs sWbkPthNme & bVrs & kExt, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
              Exit Do
          End If
      Loop

      MsgBox "Version """ & bVrs & """ of workbook: " & _
          vbLf & vbLf & Chr(34) & sWbkStd & Chr(34) & " has been created.", _
          vbApplicationModal + vbInformation, "Workbook - Save a New Version - Xlsm"

  HdeThs:
      Call Wbk_Hide(ThisWorkbook)

  Exit Sub
  NewWbk:
      MsgBox "Active Workbook """ & WbkAct.Name & """ has not been saved as yet." & vbLf & _
          "A new version cannot be saved!", _
          vbApplicationModal + vbCritical, "Workbook - Save New Version - Xlsm"

  End Sub


  Private Function Fil_FileExist(sFullName As String) As Boolean
  Dim sDir As String
      Fil_FileExist = (Dir(sFullName) <> Empty)
  End Function


  Private Sub Wbk_Hide(Wbk As Workbook)
  Dim Wnd As Window
      For Each Wnd In Wbk.Windows
          Wnd.Visible = False
      Next
  End Sub
  ```